# Concatenate 2 value in a map key

Tags: apex, map

I need to retrieve an Id value through 2 other values (of type string) :
each Id of an object can be identified by a code (Code__c) and another value (Value__c).

How can I retrieve this Id passing by the 2 other field ?

I thought use a `Map<String, Id>` so the key (String) would be the 2 others values and then I can retrieve the Id, but is it possible to concatenate the key ?

I have 2 value and I have to use only one...
If you have any idea, thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, We can have two values concatenated in **String as Key** inside Map and **Id as Value**. We can retrieve the id by passing the Key (two other fields) as mentioned in below solution.

**SOLUTION:**

```
Map<String, ID> mapDemo = new Map<String, ID>();

Obj__c  t = [Select Id, Code__c, Value__c From Obj__c Limit 1];

//Putting Key and Value
String key = t.Code__c + t.Value__c ;
mapDemo.put(key , t.Id );

//Getting Id based on the two other field
Id objId = mapDemo.get(key);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do something like

```
string temp = Code__c + '#'+Value__c
tempMap.Put(temp, recordid);
```

Now when you want to retrieve id then split the string or conact another string and then compare. it will help you.